# apache2 oom_killer killed mariadb

Tags: apache2, mysql, mariadb

Discovered mariadb was down and found this logging in syslog.

Apache is running mediawiki and wordpress. Could it be a rogue Wordpress plugin?

It looks like apache told linux to kill mariadb - is that right? But it looks like the memory is being eaten up by apache processes.

I've restarted mariadb and all is running smoothly. But obviously it'd be good to nail down what happened.

Lastly, that last few lines of logging from mysql - I thought it must be a relic from a previous failed upgrade, so I reran `mysql_upgrade` but it still appears. Maybe a red herring?

```
kernel: [10611116.459217] apache2 invoked oom-killer: 
gfp_mask=0x100dca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_ZERO), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
kernel: [10611116.459235] CPU: 0 PID: 1853986 Comm: apache2 Not tainted 5.10.0-18-amd64 #1 Debian 5.10.140-1
kernel: [10611116.459240] Call Trace:
kernel: [10611116.459254]  dump_stack+0x6b/0x83
kernel: [10611116.459259]  dump_header+0x4a/0x1f4
kernel: [10611116.459263]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
kernel: [10611116.459269]  out_of_memory+0x1bd/0x4e0
kernel: [10611116.459275]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0xb90/0xc60
kernel: [10611116.459280]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x2de/0x310
kernel: [10611116.459285]  alloc_pages_vma+0x80/0x270
kernel: [10611116.459290]  handle_mm_fault+0xe80/0x1c10
kernel: [10611116.459296]  do_user_addr_fault+0x1b8/0x400
kernel: [10611116.459301]  exc_page_fault+0x78/0x160
kernel: [10611116.459306]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
kernel: [10611116.459309]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x1e/0x30
kernel: [10611116.459314] RIP: e033:0x7f3768de20ed
kernel: [10611116.459317] Code: 10 48 85 c0 74 57 48 8b 50 20 48 39 da 72 ee 48 8d 4b 40 48 39 ca 0f 86 41 01 00 00 48 89 d1 48 29 d9 48 8d 2c 08 48 89 48 20 <48> 89 4d 08 48 89 5c 10 08 48 89 5d 00 48 8d 3d 7f 82 07 00 48 01
kernel: [10611116.459324] RSP: e02b:00007ffd913ed070 EFLAGS: 00010206
kernel: [10611116.459328] RAX: 00007f37585d0510 RBX: 0000000000000620 RCX: 000000000000e7d8
kernel: [10611116.459332] RDX: 000000000000edf8 RSI: 0000000000000006 RDI: 0000000000000030
kernel: [10611116.459336] RBP: 00007f37585dece8 R08: 0000561de5362290 R09: 0000000000000000
kernel: [10611116.459339] R10: 0000000000000040 R11: 0000000000000040 R12: 0000000000000040
kernel: [10611116.459342] R13: 00007f37585d0510 R14: 00007ffd913ed180 R15: 0000000000000000
kernel: [10611116.459347] Mem-Info:
kernel: [10611116.459352] active_anon:262884 inactive_anon:434934 isolated_anon:2503
kernel: [10611116.459352]  active_file:1599 inactive_file:1067 isolated_file:153
kernel: [10611116.459352]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:101
kernel: [10611116.459352]  slab_reclaimable:6679 slab_unreclaimable:22736
kernel: [10611116.459352]  mapped:8785 shmem:6428 pagetables:13879 bounce:0
kernel: [10611116.459352]  free:6616 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
kernel: [10611116.459365] Node 0 active_anon:1051536kB inactive_anon:1739736kB active_file:6396kB inactive_file:4268kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):10012kB isolated(file):612kB mapped:35140kB dirty:0kB writeback:404kB shmem:25712kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:6224kB all_unreclaimable? no
kernel: [10611116.459411] Node 0 DMA free:11452kB min:36kB low:48kB high:60kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:2224kB inactive_anon:2024kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15996kB managed:15912kB mlocked:0kB pagetables:68kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
kernel: [10611116.459424] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2855 2855 2855 2855
kernel: [10611116.459429] Node 0 DMA32 free:15012kB min:25812kB low:28736kB high:31660kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:1049260kB inactive_anon:1737712kB active_file:6396kB inactive_file:4268kB unevictable:0kB writepending:380kB present:3129344kB managed:3031636kB mlocked:0kB pagetables:55448kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
kernel: [10611116.459442] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
kernel: [10611116.459446] Node 0 DMA: 9*4kB (UM) 5*8kB (UE) 11*16kB (UE) 12*32kB (UME) 11*64kB (UME) 7*128kB (UE) 6*256kB (UME) 5*512kB (UME) 3*1024kB (UME) 1*2048kB (U) 0*4096kB = 11452kB
kernel: [10611116.459464] Node 0 DMA32: 912*4kB (UME) 134*8kB (UME) 399*16kB (UME) 123*32kB (UE) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 15040kB
kernel: [10611116.459476] 73536 total pagecache pages
kernel: [10611116.459479] 64309 pages in swap cache
kernel: [10611116.459483] Swap cache stats: add 1237051, delete 1172742, find 11890429/12053780
kernel: [10611116.459491] Free swap  = 0kB
kernel: [10611116.459493] Total swap = 2097148kB
kernel: [10611116.459496] 786335 pages RAM
kernel: [10611116.459499] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
kernel: [10611116.459502] 24448 pages reserved
kernel: [10611116.459505] 0 pages hwpoisoned
kernel: [10611116.459508] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
kernel: [10611116.459511] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
kernel: [10611116.459517] [    174]     0   174    18346      209   159744      275          -250 systemd-journal
kernel: [10611116.459522] [    195]     0   195     5330       85    65536      118         -1000 systemd-udevd
kernel: [10611116.459527] [    299]   100   299    22110       75    73728       98             0 systemd-timesyn
kernel: [10611116.459532] [    305]     0   305      937      102    45056       29             0 cron
kernel: [10611116.459536] [    306]   106   306     2063      185    61440       62          -900 dbus-daemon
kernel: [10611116.459541] [    310]     0   310    55200      190    69632      160             0 rsyslogd
kernel: [10611116.459546] [    312]     0   312     3471      210    73728      103             0 systemd-logind
kernel: [10611116.459551] [    317]     0   317     2192      186    53248      102             0 vsftpd
kernel: [10611116.459556] [    318]     0   318     1462       26    49152        2             0 agetty
kernel: [10611116.459561] [    319]     0   319      627       66    40960        2             0 agetty
kernel: [10611116.459566] [    324]     0   324   301986     1617   282624     2936          -999 containerd
kernel: [10611116.459571] [    363]     0   363     3339      170    69632      195         -1000 sshd
kernel: [10611116.459579] [    402]   108   402   288810    27826   987136    60311             0 mariadbd
kernel: [10611116.459584] [    409]     0   409    68199     1254   217088     2238             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459589] [    415]     0   415   306358     2680   335872     2033          -500 dockerd
kernel: [10611116.459594] [    735]   110   735     4651      150    73728      175             0 exim4
kernel: [10611116.459599] [1853716]    33 1853716    93968    11154   393216     5458             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459604] [1853717]    33 1853717    75401    10849   380928     5552             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459608] [1853718]    33 1853718    94029    10103   389120     6851             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459613] [1853719]    33 1853719    75374    12035   376832     4554             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459617] [1853720]    33 1853720    93989    10360   393216     6547             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459622] [1853721]    33 1853721    94817    10910   442368     5483             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459627] [1853736]    33 1853736    94082     9121   393216     7651             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459632] [1853737]    33 1853737    94835     9916   446464     6303             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459636] [1853762]    33 1853762    76244    11057   430080     5416             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459647] [1853898]    33 1853898    75307    10143   376832     6331             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459655] [1853899]    33 1853899    75284    11334   376832     4867             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459660] [1853900]    33 1853900    75268    11372   376832     4797             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459665] [1853901]    33 1853901    75284    10531   376832     5618             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459670] [1853902]    33 1853902    75268    11161   376832     4715             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459674] [1853903]    33 1853903    75284    10851   376832     5309             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459679] [1853904]    33 1853904    73732    10423   364544     3853             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459683] [1853905]    33 1853905    75284    10964   376832     5369             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459688] [1853906]    33 1853906    73716     8900   364544     5096             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459693] [1853907]    33 1853907    75284    11409   376832     4859             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459698] [1853908]    33 1853908    75284    10900   376832     5267             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459703] [1853909]    33 1853909    75268    11068   376832     4826             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459707] [1853910]    33 1853910    75284    10940   376832     5280             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459712] [1853911]    33 1853911    73124    10394   352256     3005             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459717] [1853912]    33 1853912    75268    12008   376832     3514             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459725] [1853913]    33 1853913    75307    11809   376832     4673             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459731] [1853914]    33 1853914    75268    11960   376832     3950             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459737] [1853915]    33 1853915    75268    11700   376832     4355             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459742] [1853916]    33 1853916    75307    12220   376832     4262             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459746] [1853917]    33 1853917    75284     9399   376832     6924             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459751] [1853918]    33 1853918    74756    11006   372736     4241             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459755] [1853919]    33 1853919    75268    10811   376832     5270             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459760] [1853920]    33 1853920    75284    10983   376832     5283             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459765] [1853921]    33 1853921    75268    11438   376832     4331             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459770] [1853922]    33 1853922    75284    11246   376832     4993             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459774] [1853923]    33 1853923    73716    11044   364544     3090             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459779] [1853924]    33 1853924    75268    11962   376832     4036             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459784] [1853925]    33 1853925    75307    11243   376832     5238             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459794] [1853926]    33 1853926    75284    10691   376832     5648             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459800] [1853927]    33 1853927    75284    11499   376832     4766             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459805] [1853928]    33 1853928    75268    10557   376832     5335             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459809] [1853929]    33 1853929    73716     9662   360448     4462             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459814] [1853930]    33 1853930    73716     9716   364544     4258             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459819] [1853931]    33 1853931    75284    11211   376832     4987             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459824] [1853932]    33 1853932    75268    10873   376832     5258             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459829] [1853933]    33 1853933    75305    11131   376832     5255             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459833] [1853934]    33 1853934    75268    11015   376832     5102             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459838] [1853937]    33 1853937    74756    10001   372736     5013             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459843] [1853938]    33 1853938    75268    10943   376832     5125             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459847] [1853939]    33 1853939    75307    10290   376832     6194             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459852] [1853940]    33 1853940    75268    12378   376832     3630             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459857] [1853941]    33 1853941    75268    10400   376832     5676             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459865] [1853942]    33 1853942    75268    10747   376832     5215             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459870] [1853943]    33 1853943    75284    11173   376832     5127             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459875] [1853944]    33 1853944    75268    10819   376832     4942             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459880] [1853945]    33 1853945    73732     9836   364544     4655             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459885] [1853946]    33 1853946    75268    11235   376832     4931             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459889] [1853947]    33 1853947    75284    11457   376832     4850             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459894] [1853948]    33 1853948    74244     9371   368640     5582             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459899] [1853949]    33 1853949    75300    11069   376832     5352             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459903] [1853950]    33 1853950    75284    10113   376832     6200             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459908] [1853951]    33 1853951    75284     9722   376832     6602             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459913] [1853952]    33 1853952    75284    10801   376832     5428             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459917] [1853953]    33 1853953    73716     9049   364544     5028             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459923] [1853954]    33 1853954    75268    11061   376832     4939             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459929] [1853955]    33 1853955    75268    11092   376832     4643             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459935] [1853956]    33 1853956    74756    10596   372736     4954             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459940] [1853957]    33 1853957    75268    10844   376832     5200             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459945] [1853958]    33 1853958    73204     9368   356352     4493             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459949] [1853959]    33 1853959    75284    11141   376832     5167             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459954] [1853960]    33 1853960    73204    10314   360448     3632             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459959] [1853961]    33 1853961    75268    11093   376832     4816             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459964] [1853962]    33 1853962    75268    10539   376832     5319             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459969] [1853963]    33 1853963    75268    10905   376832     4816             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459973] [1853964]    33 1853964    75268    12272   376832     3716             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459978] [1853965]    33 1853965    73732     9652   364544     4595             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459983] [1853966]    33 1853966    75268    10651   376832     5459             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459987] [1853967]    33 1853967    73124     8280   352256     4743             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459992] [1853968]    33 1853968    75268    10787   376832     5366             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.459997] [1853969]    33 1853969    73732     9176   364544     4982             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460003] [1853970]    33 1853970    73204     9038   356352     4834             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460010] [1853971]    33 1853971    75268    11388   376832     4429             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460015] [1853972]    33 1853972    73716    10041   364544     4339             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460020] [1853973]    33 1853973    72612     9521   348160     2979             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460024] [1853974]    33 1853974    73716    10575   360448     3619             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460029] [1853975]    33 1853975    75268    10992   376832     4904             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460034] [1853976]    33 1853976    73204    10088   356352     3861             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460039] [1853977]    33 1853977    75268    11353   376832     4724             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460044] [1853978]    33 1853978    73732    10527   364544     3943             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460048] [1853979]    33 1853979    74756    10480   372736     4775             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460053] [1853980]    33 1853980    75268    10657   376832     5519             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460058] [1853981]    33 1853981    73700    10313   356352     3690             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460062] [1853982]    33 1853982    73716     9491   360448     4676             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460068] [1853983]    33 1853983    75268    11096   376832     5110             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460079] [1853984]    33 1853984    75300    11621   376832     4801             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460085] [1853985]    33 1853985    75284    11173   376832     5020             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460090] [1853986]    33 1853986    73156     9817   352256     3584             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460094] [1853987]    33 1853987    73716     9080   360448     5069             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460099] [1853988]    33 1853988    75268    11217   376832     4869             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460104] [1853989]    33 1853989    73716    10047   364544     4332             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460108] [1853990]    33 1853990    73204     9228   356352     4557             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460113] [1853991]    33 1853991    75284    11788   376832     4606             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460118] [1853992]    33 1853992    73732    10463   364544     3983             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460122] [1853993]    33 1853993    73732    11561   364544     2864             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460127] [1853994]    33 1853994    75284    10487   376832     5886             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460132] [1853995]    33 1853995    75284    11236   376832     4977             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460136] [1853996]    33 1853996    75268    12342   376832     3697             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460142] [1853997]    33 1853997    75268    10659   376832     5568             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460148] [1853998]    33 1853998    73732    10517   364544     3683             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460158] [1853999]    33 1853999    75284    10903   376832     5464             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460163] [1854000]    33 1854000    73716     9485   364544     4842             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460168] [1854001]    33 1854001    75268    10682   376832     5391             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460173] [1854002]    33 1854002    75268    11081   376832     4828             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460177] [1854003]    33 1854003    75284    11001   376832     5217             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460182] [1854004]    33 1854004    73124    10570   352256     2789             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460187] [1854005]    33 1854005    75300     9701   376832     6656             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460191] [1854006]    33 1854006    91621     9637   360448     3938             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460196] [1854007]    33 1854007    73732     9432   364544     4979             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460200] [1854008]    33 1854008    73732    10285   364544     4228             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460205] [1854009]    33 1854009    75268    11434   376832     4467             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460211] [1854010]    33 1854010    73124     9373   352256     3748             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460218] [1854011]    33 1854011    74756     9649   372736     5595             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460223] [1854012]    33 1854012    75268    10671   376832     5457             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460228] [1854013]    33 1854013    75307    11846   376832     4626             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460233] [1854014]    33 1854014    75268    10558   376832     5401             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460238] [1854015]    33 1854015    75284    11000   376832     5300             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460242] [1854016]    33 1854016    75268    11019   376832     5062             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460247] [1854017]    33 1854017    75300    11341   376832     5158             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460252] [1854018]    33 1854018    75268    11020   376832     5097             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460256] [1854019]    33 1854019    73204    10148   356352     3800             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460261] [1854020]    33 1854020    75268    11306   376832     4781             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460268] [1854021]    33 1854021    75268    11098   376832     4811             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460273] [1854022]    33 1854022    75268    12040   376832     3999             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460277] [1854023]    33 1854023    75300    10760   376832     5647             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460282] [1854024]    33 1854024    75284    11409   376832     4788             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460287] [1854025]    33 1854025    75268    12011   376832     3959             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460292] [1854026]    33 1854026    73732     9552   364544     4980             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460299] [1854027]    33 1854027    75305    11701   376832     4704             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460304] [1854028]    33 1854028    75284    11589   376832     4612             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460310] [1854029]    33 1854029    75268    11339   376832     4418             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460314] [1854030]    33 1854030    75268    10906   376832     5038             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460319] [1854031]    33 1854031    75268    10700   376832     5407             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460324] [1854032]    33 1854032    75284    11360   376832     4925             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460328] [1854033]    33 1854033    75307    11356   376832     5134             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460333] [1854034]    33 1854034    75268    11111   376832     4996             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460338] [1854035]    33 1854035    75268    10960   376832     5006             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460343] [1854036]    33 1854036    73716    10371   360448     3602             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460348] [1854037]    33 1854037    75268    10803   376832     5159             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460352] [1854038]    33 1854038    75268    11244   376832     4808             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460357] [1854039]    33 1854039    71725    10421   348160     2790             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460363] [1854040]    33 1854040    75284    12141   376832     4123             0 apache2
kernel: [10611116.460371] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=apache2.service,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mariadb.service,task=mariadbd,pid=402,uid=108
kernel: [10611116.460541] Out of memory: Killed process 402 (mariadbd) total-vm:1155240kB, anon-rss:110768kB, file-rss:536kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:108 pgtables:964kB oom_score_adj:0
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Consumed 10h 57min 52.755s CPU time.
systemd[1]: Started Session 9821 of user adam.
systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5.15 database server...
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (mysqld 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1) starting as process 1856333 ...
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=72429154949,72429154949
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 325 pages from redo log.
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.15 started; log sequence number 72463506172; transaction id 48786325
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
mariadbd[1856333]: Version: '10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 11
systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.5.15 database server.
/etc/mysql/debian-start[1856349]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 3 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
/etc/mysql/debian-start[1856352]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
/etc/mysql/debian-start[1856352]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
/etc/mysql/debian-start[1856352]: Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
/etc/mysql/debian-start[1856352]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
/etc/mysql/debian-start[1856352]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
/etc/mysql/debian-start[1856358]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:36 4 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
debian-start[1856361]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
mariadbd[1856333]: 2023-02-10 19:15:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230210 19:15:38
```

Comment: How did you run `mysql_upgrade`? Generally I have found it necessary to first switch to the super user *before* running the upgrades. Prefixing a command with `sudo` is insufficient for some reason 

Comment: I ran it with `sudo`. I see now it runs with every restart. I'll need to work out how to set up mysql to read the password from a file.